# How to find the no of elements in an string array (the string is passed to a function)

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string> 


using namespace std;

class Prerequisites
{
    public:
    void orderClasses(string* Input);
};


void Prerequisites::orderClasses(string* Input)
{
        // Need to find the length of the array Input

}

int main()
{

    Prerequisites A;

    string classes[]={"CSE121: CSE110",
        "CSE110:",
        "MATH122:"
         };


    A.orderClasses(classes);

}
```

I need to find the length of the array classes[] in the methos orderClasses.
I cannot alter the signature of the method orderClasses ! That is a requirement.

Comment: If this isn't homework, what is this project that has such inane and stupid requirements?

Comment: Dear James, I was trying to solve one topcoder question. The requirement is such that I use the given method signature. Hope this clears your doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the number of elements in the array to `orderClasses()`.  Since that is not an option, consider some alternatives:

- Add another member function to `Prerequisites` to inform it how large the array will be when you do call `orderClasses()`.
- Use a sentinel value for the last string in the array so that when you see that value in the function, you know you have reached the end.
- Make the first string in the array a string containing the number of elements in the array.

None of these are good solutions to the problem:  the best option while still using an array, of course, is just to pass the array size to the function.  In most scenarios, it would be even better not to use an array at all and just pass a `std::vector<std::string>` containing the strings.

Comment: I am not sure , if I can change the Input or the method. But adding the the member function seems cool though!!

Answer (score 0):

The information is just not there.  Can't you add a last item to the `classes[]` array that's a "well-known end-marker/sentinel"?  That meets the requirement of not changing the method signature (you're just changing the data passed to it, not the signature;-).

Answer (score 0):

I never heard that in c++ people are using arrays when there is a far more powerful STL tools.